# Unable to do paging on gridview asp.net,

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowtype

I have code to have a dynamic button appear after it does an if else loop for checking for some data.

however, the gridview cant do any paging. it only shows the first page and cant go to 2nd page and so on.
It only can do the paging IF i nvr call the method below.

here is my code

```
 public void filter_select(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
     ........                
            }
```

that method will be called on the rowdatabound gridview page source like this `OnRowDataBound="filter_select"`

my gridview code on source code is :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" 
     HorizontalAlign="Center" OnRowCommand="stop_survey" 
       OnRowDataBound="filter_select" OnSelectedIndexChanging="selected" PageSize="5" 
    Width="133%" DataKeyNames="SurveyID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        >
          <Columns>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SurveyID" HeaderText="Survey ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                                    .........
```

my onrowCommand code

```
 public void stop_survey(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con;
    string sqlcom;
    SqlCommand cmd;

    //is it because of this code below? as if i comment from this code onwards, the paging works.
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
    Button btn = (Button)GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("btnStop");
    ...............
```

Comment: What happens when you click for the next page? Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: where do you load the data and bind the grid? if after going to page 2 you get empty grid it could be you are not binding properly.

Comment: curt, no error when going for next page. and i dont have to go to another page though.
Davide Piras, i load the data using sqldatasource. when i click on page 2, its not empty. its just that i cant even click on any other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebind your gridview in the PageIndexChanging event of the gridview control

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            GridView1.DataSource = DataAcceessLayer.GetEmployeeData();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: what is the " DataAcceessLayer.GetEmployeeData();"
im using sqldatasource

Comment: I tried to replace it with 
   GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
but its still nothing happen when i click on page 2.

Comment: DataAcceessLayer.GetEmployeeData(); is simply a method which executes a sql query and returns a DataTable object used to populate the gridview with data.Since you are using an SQL Datasource paging should be handled automatically so there is no need to rebind the data in the PageIndexChanging event, it's very puzzling that it doesn't work.Could you post markup for your gridview?

Comment: i just updated the source code for my grid view. its indeed very weird.
However, if i took out the either onrowDatabound or 'filter_select' method, the paging is working perfectly.

Comment: I've created the Survey table in SQL and re-created the page on my pc, the paging is working perfectly.The only difference is I took out OnRowCommand="stop_survey" and OnSelectedIndexChanging="selected" as you did not provide the code behind for these events.I've also removed the DynamicControl1 from the markup, perhaps have a look if any of those 3 could be causing the problem but the filter_select and paging seems to be working just fine

Comment: ah yes. thanks! its very weird that when i removed it all, and putting it back one by one it works. :)

Comment: Great!Glad that you finally managed to get it working, I was looking forward to finding out what the issue was but seems like this is just one of those ASP.NET mysteries

Comment: omg. it happen again when i change to another computer. oh my! this is driving me crazy.

Comment: now it cant do paging if i put the rowCommand.. oh god what happen!

Comment: alright. i solved it bymyself..
to take note :
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
    Button btn = (Button)GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("btnStop");

have to be put inside if else 
source : http://forums.asp.net/t/1626128.aspx/1